# Jquery Array Pass it to BackEnd C# MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, arrays, asp.net-mvc

I have a JQuery Array and it needs to pass to the backend.But thatone not passed.Here i have paste the coding parts.

### TuitionDTO

```
 public class TuitionDTO
{
    public int TuitionId { get; set; }
    public string TuitionTitle { get; set; }

    public List<ClassCoverageDTO> ClassCoverage { get; set; }
}
```

### ClassCoverageDTO

```
  public class ClassCoverageDTO
{
    public int ClassCoverageId { get; set; }
    public int TuitionId { get; set; }
    public int DistrictId { get; set; }
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public string Place { get; set; }
    public DateTime? AddedDate { get; set; }
    public string AddedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }

    //Display Purpose Only
    public string DistrictName { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
}
```

### Add Items To JQuery Array

```
    function AddClassCoverage(_districtId, _cityId, _place, _districtName, _cityName) {
$('<tr id=' + rowId + '><td id=' + _districtId + '>' + _districtName + '</td><td id=' + _cityId + '>' + _cityName + '</td><td id=' + _place + '>' + _place + '<td id="my">X</td></tr>').appendTo("#responsive-table-example tbody");

            var coverage = {
                DistrictId: _districtId,
                CityId: _cityId,
                Place: _place,
                DistrictName: _districtName,
                CityName: _cityName
        };
        CoverageItemsArr.push(coverage);
 rowId++;
```

}

### HTML PART

```
    <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Add Class Coverage<span id="ast">*</span></label>
                                <table id="responsive-table-example" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>District</th>
                                            <th>City/Town</th>
                                            <th>Place</th>
                                            <th>Action</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>
                                                <select class="form-control" name="district" id="iddistrict"></select>
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                <select class="form-control" name="city" id="idcity"></select>
                                            </th>
                                            <th> <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" placeholder="" name="place" id="idplace"></th>
                                            <th><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="addClassCoverage()">Add</button></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody id="coveragetable"></tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

### Append to FormData and pass it to Backend

```
//Append to FormData and Send to Backend via AJAX CALL

        formData.append("ClassCoverage", CoverageItemsArr)

        $.ajax({
            url: $("#addTuitionDetails").val(),
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            mimeType: 'multipart/form-data',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (status) {
              alert("Success");
            }
        });
        return true;
```

Comment: What kind of structure is FormData? Dictionary? An object? If it is an object I'd expect to see something like `FormData.ClassCoverage = CoverageItemsArr` or if it is a dictionary then `FormData["ClassCoverage"] = CoverageItemsArr`

Comment: @Nesaje it's a object like  `var formData = new FormData();`

Comment: @Nesaje I've tried that you have mentioned above types but still failed.

Comment: Please share Controller's Action method which supposed to handle ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

do you have a controller that suppose to handle the ajax request ?

```
   [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult AjaxRequest(string yourvalue)
    {
        string returendvalue = "";
        return Json(returendvalue, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

'

here is an example for controller function ,

now in the ajax request

```
     $.ajax({
        url:'@Url.RouteUrl(new { action="AjaxRequest",Controller="Your Controller"})',
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        mimeType: 'multipart/form-data',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (status) {
          alert("Success");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes i have a Httppost control in backend other single values successfully send.but only this array not send to backend

Comment: try passing everything as string and debug it when the controller is fired , make sure every property is valid , maybe somthing is not valid preventing to C# deserialize to object . ClassCoverageDTO for example int as null .. make sure to create default value -1\ 0 or create nullable property  by using int? instead of int .  best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `TuitionDTO` is parameter of your controller action I'd try this (just to see if values bind correctly):
Replace line 
`formData.append("ClassCoverage", CoverageItemsArr)` with hardcoded value:

```
var formData =
{
    TuitionId: 1,
    TuitionTitle: "Tuition title",
    ClassCoverage: [
        {
                DistrictId: 1,
                CityId: 1,
                Place: "Some place",
                DistrictName: "Some district",
                CityName: "Some city",
                ClassCoverageId: 1,
                TuitionId: 1,
                AddedBy: "someone",
                ModifiedBy: "someone else"
        },
        {
                DistrictId: 2,
                CityId: 2,
                Place: "Some other place",
                DistrictName: "Some other district",
                CityName: "Some other city",
                ClassCoverageId: 2,
                TuitionId: 2,
                AddedBy: "someone",
                ModifiedBy: "someone else"
        }
    ]
}
```

Try this out. If it works, then just replace actual values and ClassCoverage like this

```
var formData =
{
    TuitionId: $("#whatever_holds_it").val(),
    TuitionTitle: $("#whatever_holds_title").val(),
    ClassCoverage: CoverageItemsArr
}
```

If it doesn't work yet, try setting all properties of the coverage object and see what happens.
Otherwise, we'd need your controller action (only its signature, not the body).
Make sure you have `[HttpPost]' attribute above your action.